# How to reload config data in running Flask instance?

Tags: python, flask, resources

Suppose we have a service that uses filesystem config file to get some job done:

```
class Service:

    def _load():
        # (re)loads config file
        pass

    def do_some_work():
        # uses config file
        pass
```

... and a Flask app that provides the service to its clients.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
service = Service()

@app.route('/do-some-work')
def do_some_work():
    return service.do_some_work()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The question is how to **manually reload** config file **without restarting Flask/gunicorn** instance.

I'm sorry if the question sounds a bit weird. I'm well aware about classic approaches:

- monitoring config file (dir) for changes via [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) or its alternative
- setting up some timer to check file modification date at fixed intervals, e.g. [Flask-APScheduler](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler)
- adding extra endpoint like `@app.route('/reload')`

In my case they all have various drawbacks. I just hope that is possible to build some cli that can interact with running Python process without using HTTP. But since I'm not a Python expert I'm not well informed about WSGI process isolation.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, the answer is [RPyC](https://github.com/tomerfiliba-org/rpyc), but either gunicorn should be started with single worker only or app have to use some kind of cache to store config data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal). Here is an example with [SIGHUP](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/signals.html#master-process).

```
# debug.py
import signal
from flask import Flask, jsonify


class Service:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._config = ''
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        with open('config.txt') as f:
            self._config = f.readlines()

    def do_some_work(self):
        return self._config


app = Flask(__name__)
service = Service()


@app.route('/do-some-work')
def do_some_work():
    # just result of parsed / loaded config
    return jsonify(dict(config=service.do_some_work()))


def handler(signum, frame):
    service.load()


# add SIGHUP handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

open 1 terminal:

```
echo 1 >> config.txt
gunicorn -p app.pid -w 4 'debug:app'
```

open 2 terminal:

```
# let's check loaded / parsed config 
curl http://localhost:8000/do-some-work
# {"config":["1\n"]}
# let's change config
echo "2345" >> config.txt
# let's send HUP
cat app.pid | xargs kill -HUP
# let's check config value
curl http://localhost:8000/do-some-work
# {"config":["1\n","2345\n"]}
```